# Excel Outlook VBA: DeferredDeliveryTime: Not working

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I am testing if deferred delivery time works and see that these emails are not sent. I see nothing in the outbox. 
Emails do get sent if i just .Send and comment out .DeferredDeliveryTime.
Also, I've tried manually changing Do not deliver before time in Outlook and that does work. 
So I am not sure what is going wrong here with the VBA.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olAccount As Outlook.Account

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With olMail

.To = "my email"
.Subject = "test"
.Body = "test"

' .Send
 .DeferredDeliveryTime = DateAdd("n", 10, Now)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Figured I also need to add `.Send` after `.DeferredDeliveryTime`. The examples here - http://www.vboffice.net/en/developers/send-delay/ do not do that.

Comment: The examples below are changing the `Application_ItemSend` function, so I don't think this works like you think it does

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41318693/4539709

Comment: I added `.Send` after ``.DeferredDeliveryTime = DateAdd("n", 5, (DateAdd("h", -5.5, Now)))`` but now all emails are being sent immediately. Not sure why.  I am using ``(DateAdd("h", -5.5, Now)`` in `Now`'s place to adjust for the time zone. Outlook is using UTC time zone by default which i need to convert to local time zone.

Comment: There's no need to change the time zone. When manually changing the Delay Delivery do not send before time, I had to change the time to UTC. Don't need to do this in VBA apparently.

Answer (score 2):

According to my test, You should change `.DeferredDeliveryTime = DateAdd("n", 10, Now)` Position, like this:

```
Dim olAccount As Outlook.Account

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With olMail
.To = "email address"
.Subject = "test"
.Body = "test"
.DeferredDeliveryTime = DateAdd("n", 10, Now)
.Send

End With

End Sub
```

This code is run success in my PC.

Comment: Thanks. Adding `.Send` is what I was missing. `.DeferredDeliveryTime = DateAdd("n", 10, Now)` does not send the email.

Comment: .DeferredDeliveryTime will delayed send email. Have you been waiting for some time? Please refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.deferreddeliverytime

Comment: .DeferredDeliveryTime = DateAdd("n", 10, Now) will send email after ten minutes. For more information, please refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41297105/how-can-i-automatically-send-an-email-with-delay-from-an-outlook-inbox-usign-vba