# Outlook VBA: Check if delay delivery is already set

Tags: vba, email, outlook

The question of how to delay email delivery programmatically in Outlook through VBA is already well addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597033/delay-sending-mail), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41297105/how-can-i-automatically-send-an-email-with-delay-from-an-outlook-inbox-usign-vba), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53000106/excel-outlook-vba-deferreddeliverytime-not-working), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67914552/how-to-change-the-delivery-date-and-time-of-a-message) for example.

I've implemented a version in `Application_ItemSend` that mostly suits my needs. But right now it *always* applies a delay delivery if the email is being sent before a certain time of day.

**How do I check if delay delivery is *already* set?** In which case I might opt not to change it, or to compare the already-set date/time against some earlier allowed time or whatever.

To try to figure this out, I printed `Item.DeferredDeliveryTime` before and after my code that adds delay delivery:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Debug.Print "Item.DeferredDeliveryTime: " & Item.DeferredDeliveryTime

    ' My code to delay delivery is here. 
    
    Debug.Print "Item.DeferredDeliveryTime: " & Item.DeferredDeliveryTime
    
End Sub
```

When I run this on a fresh email, so delay delivery is not set at the beginning, I get the following:

```
Item.DeferredDeliveryTime: 4501-01-01

Item.DeferredDeliveryTime: 2023-07-20 6:31:00 AM
```

So my code has determined that a delay delivery is required and applied one for 6:31am today. But before doing that, the `Item.DeferredDeliveryTime` was set to this strange number 4501-01-01 that looks like a date with no time.

Is that initial number just a *date-formatted* Outlook code that means "no delay delivery is set"? Or is that an actual date, set very far out (~2500 years in this case) so that Outlook ignores it?

In either case, is that number constant? I.e. will all emails on all systems at all times show the same number when delay delivery is not set? Meaning I can just check the value against that constant. Or is it variable, requiring some parsing to determine if it's a "very far away" date, in which case we'd assume delay delivery is not set?

OR, am I heading down the wrong path and there is a better way to determine if delay delivery has already been set than looking at `Item.DeferredDeliveryTime`?

Thanks.

Comment: Every other source (non-stackoverflow) that I've read so far mentioned the 4501 in one form or another, i.e. not only "4501-01-01" but also "1/01/4501". It should be the the date of "no-delay" set. Could turn it into a string and search for the "4501" just to be certain on any system. Sources: [first](https://medium.com/@moral.pere/thank-you-2ca82265fd89) and [second](https://forums.slipstick.com/threads/95140-vba-to-remove-deferred-delivery-on-a-meetingitem/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `DateTime` is not nullable (it is an 8 byte float in COM), the only way to designate "no-value" is to use a special value, which is `1/1/4501`. Outlook always uses that value for its DateTime properties that are not set.

Comment: Thanks! That special date value seems pretty obscure. After you provided this answer, I did some quick searching and couldn't find a clear documentation of it, although I did find this doc which makes some reference to it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olmarkinterval

Comment: Yep, they had to pick a value that won't likely be used (hence the year 4501). 0 wouldn't work since that would be 1/1/1899, which is likely be used as a real value.