# How to change the delivery date and time of a message?

Tags: vba, outlook

In a new email message OR a reply message, I want to change the delivery date and time to the next day at a certain time, say 8AM.

I want to be able to click one button in my toolbar and the date and time to be set automatically.

Delayed Delivery
[image]

Macro Needed
[image]

Comment: I am using this macro, but it creates a new email, I need to be able to append to an existing email thread or reply.                                                                                    
Public Sub SendDeferredMessage()
Dim objMsg As MailItem
Dim SendAt

Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'send at 8:24 AM. .25 = 6 AM, .50 = noon
SendAt = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now)) + 0.35

  objMsg.DeferredDeliveryTime = SendAt

  'displays the message form
  objMsg.Display
  
  Set objMsg = Nothing

End Sub

Comment: Please include it in your question, not in a comment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41318693/4539709

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are creating a new MailItem instance where the [MailItem.DeferredDeliveryTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.deferreddeliverytime) property is set which stands for a date indicating the date and time the mail message is to be delivered.

Instead, you need to get the current item displayed in the inspector window in Outlook. To get this done, you need to use the [ActiveInspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.activeinspector) property which returns the topmost `Inspector` object on the desktop.

```
Sub GetCurrentItem()
 Dim myinspector As Outlook.Inspector 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 
 Set myinspector = Application.ActiveInspector 
 Set myItem = myinspector.CurrentItem 
End Sub
```